# i want to implement web view with camera access but showing this error app:mergeDexDebug FAILED

Tags: flutter

I tried to run my flutter app but it is showing this error.  i want to implement with camera access

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform classes.jar (project :webview_flutter_android) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr=7.3.0, com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr=debug, com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr=debug, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=19, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\onmarkt_web_view\build\webview_flutter_android\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\debug\classes.jar.
> > Error while dexing.